# Get an average for each column depending on the value in another column

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, average, spreadsheet

I have the table bellow where each column from J to M are prices for a certain activities.

Column I is the Size

I want to create a new table where automatically to be calculated the AVERAGE for each column where "I" is equal to something (112, 132, 160 and so on...)

[image]

Comment: have you tried countifs? - https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en-GB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(J5:J19; $I5:$I19; 132)
```

Comment: @BochoTodorov this is also possible: `=AVERAGEIF($I5:$I19; 132; J5:J19)` if you got only 1 criteria